# INNER JOIN taking up too much time

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my database, I have a table called FinanceProfile. It has a column called FinanceProfileId.

I have another table called FinanceProfileState. This table has a foreign key called FinanceProfileId that references to the record in FinanceProfile Table.

I have stored proc which does the following:-

I have a temp table called @MatchingContactFinancialProfiles.

```
DECLARE @MatchingContactFinancialProfiles TABLE
( 
   FinanceProfileId int,
   ContactId uniqueidentifier
);
```

@MatchingContactFinancialProfiles contains subset of FinanceProfile table. It contains about 100 rows.

FinanceProfileState table has about 4500 matching rows with @MatchingContactFinancialProfiles.

I am doing a join like this:

```
INSERT INTO @FinanceProfileStates
       SELECT distinct fpState.FinanaceProfileId, fpState.StateId
          FROM @MatchingContactFinancialProfiles fp inner JOIN FinanaceProfileState fpState
          on fp.FinanceProfileId = fpState.FinanaceProfileId
```

I ran the profiler and it says from right to left:

```
Step 1: Table Scan @MatchingContactFinancialProfiles  - Cost 5%
Step 2:  A) Hash Match Aggregate- 19%
         B) Clustered Index Scan - Table - FinanaceProfileState  PK - FinanaceProfileStateId - 15%
Step 3: Hash Match - Inner Join - 38%
Step 4: Distinct Sort - 15%
Step 5: Insert @FinanceProfileStates - 8%
```

This query takes up most time in the stored procedure. What can I do to make this query run faster ?

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any indexes on your `@MatchingContactFinancialProfiles` table variable.

Try using

```
DECLARE @MatchingContactFinancialProfiles TABLE
( 
   FinanceProfileId int PRIMARY KEY,
   ContactId uniqueidentifier
);
```

According to this [link](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/create-index-on-table-variable) you can also get better performance by using a temp table rather than the table variable that you are currently using.

Comment: that has significantly reduced the time. Thanks for your input. However, I would like it to be a little less. In General when we do joins on tables, is there a thumb rule to make it faster such as using indexes on the columns we are using.

Comment: I always try to join on indexed columns. If `fpState.FinanaceProfileId` isn't indexed then you should add one.